# Accessing keys and value of objects within objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've been looking around for awhile and can't seem to find an answer to the problem I'm facing. I'm new so there's a fairly high chance I'm simply doing what I'm trying to do wrongly. The purpose of what I'm doing is simply to learn what I can and can't do with object, arrays, and loops so as I go through this project with what I want to do, I'm slowly figuring out how to do these things.

So what I have here are a bunch of objects (with keys and values). I'm going to store each of these individual (Character) objects into another object called Characters.

```
function Character(sociability, assertiveness, adventurous, emotionalExpressiveness, kindness,  altruism, affection, trust, impulseControl, thoughtfullness, emotionalStability, sexuality, evil, intellectualCuriosity, novelty, interests, intelligence) {
    "use strict";
    this.sociability = sociability;
    this.assertiveness = assertiveness;
    this.adventurous = adventurous;
    this.emotionalExpressiveness = emotionalExpressiveness;
    this.kindness = kindness;
    this.altruism = altruism;
    this.affection = affection;
    this.trust = trust;
    this.impulseControl = impulseControl;
    this.thoughtfullness = thoughtfullness;
    this.emotionalStability = emotionalStability;
    this.sexuality = sexuality;
    this.evil = evil;
    this.intellectualCuriosity = intellectualCuriosity;
    this.novelty = novelty;
    this.interests = interests;
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
}

var aloy = new Character(0, 11, 11, 0,  11, 11, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  10, 0,  0,  0),
    bayonetta = new Character(0, 10, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  13, 14, 17, 0,  11, 0,  0),
    elizabeth = new Character(0, 0, 0,  0,  11, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  12, 12, 12, 12),
    ellie = new Character(0, 12, 0, 10, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  10, 0,  11, 10),

//store all above objects into new object
var Users = {
    aloy: aloy,
    bayonetta: bayonetta,
    elizabeth: elizabeth,
    ellie: ellie,
};
```

After this I create an array that includes the names of 5 of the keys from the Character object:

```
var matchArr = ["sociability", "assertiveness", "adventurous", "emotionalExpressiveness", "kindness"]
```

Here's the part that I'm stuck at and I'll try to explain it as best I can. I'll show you the code first and then try to make sense of what I'm wanting to do.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (var obj in Users) {
        if (Users.obj.matchArr[0] > 1) {
            console.log(obj)
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is loop through the `Users` object and if one of the object within that object (the `Characters`) has a key with a value that satisfies my `if` statement, log the name of that Character object.

-If I log `for (var obj in Users) { console.log(obj); }` I loop through each `Character` name that's stored in `Users`, as expected.

-If I log `matchArr[0]` by itslef I get `"sociability"` as expected from my `matchArr` array.

-If I log `Users.aloy.sociability` I get `0` as expected as it's the value of `aloy.sociability`

-BUT if I log `Characters.aloy.matchArr[0]` I get an error (Cannot read property '0' of undefined). I don't see why this is different than explicitly typing `sociability` since this is the exact value of `matchArr[0]`.

How do I properly reference `Users.aloy.sociability` for example in the way I'm attempting to. In my head it makes sense that when I reference `Users.obj.matchArr[0]` it's the same as explicitly typing `Users.aloy.sociability`, Users.bayonetta.sociability` (and so on as it loops).

Again, I might be going about this entirely wrong and I'd appreciate any help even if it's just pointing me to other documentation that I can read through and get a better understanding that might lead me in the right direction.

My only guess is that the Array values (e.g. `matchArr[0] > "sociability"`) is a string and I can't use strings that way. If so, I don't know what to do about it.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Please make your code examples shorter. You only need a few characters with a few attributes to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop should print the character name and what attribute the character matches.

```
for (var key in Users) {
  matchArr.forEach(function(el) {
    if (Users[key][el] > 1) {
      console.log(key + ' matches attribute of ' + el);
    }
  });
}
```

Working [code example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96gnh3jf/).

Comment: This got me pointed in the right direction and I was able to adapt it to what I needed. I was able to leave out the initial FOR loop I was using and just use the "for (var key in Users) {}" part. The biggest thing looked like I was writing the rest wrong. Writing it as Users[key][matchArr[0]] is working for what I need right now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see:

```
//loop each Users

for(character in Users) {
  //Loop each matchArr
  matchArr.forEach(function(skill) {
    //at this point we are testing something like this:
    //If Users['aloy']['sociability'] > 1      
    if(Users[character][skill] > 1) {
      //log aloy
      console.log(character);
    }
  }
}
```